# Several css files after merge

Tags: magento2, merge-css

I see there are several CSS files loading on the page after Magento 2 merge. Is it possible to have only one merged CSS file? Any details how Magento 2 merge works appreciated.

```
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="https://domain.biz/static/_cache/merged/5af932c28d9dc7c83a71486116da185c.min.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="screen and (min-width: 768px)" href="https://domain.biz/static/frontend/Codazon/fastest_westylejewelry/en_US/css/styles-l.min.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="print" href="https://domain.biz/static/frontend/Codazon/fastest_westylejewelry/en_US/css/print.min.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="https://domain.biz/static/_cache/merged/eb7dcc152973e076bb2b4c94f76fe412.min.css" />
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of view source of your page?

Comment: @SukumarGorai sorry, I didn't get what you mean by 'view source of your page'

Comment: press ctrl+U and take a screenshot which gives the idea of css loaded on head? Can you please confirm that all css are loaded on your head section for from any phtml file?

Comment: @SukumarGorai I've updated my question, there are links from view source.

Comment: I think this will help https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Less-to-Sass/Merging-all-css/m-p/60414#M115

Comment: @DmitriPortenko were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @NID nope, I didn't.

Comment: @DmitriPortenko Thanks  for the reply :D